# What is the file path I need to use to view my html pages in my java project on netbeans?

Tags: java, html, netbeans

I am using NetBeans IDE 8.2.  I have a java web project, lets call it ProjectName.  My project folder looks like this:

```
>ProjectName
  >build
  >dist
  >nbproject
  >src
  >web
    >index.html
    >foo.html
    >bar.html
  >build.xml
```

Right now, if I run my project, a browser will open and display index.html.  The URL reads "localhost:54782/ProjectName".

But I cannot view foo.html or bar.html.  I have tried "localhost:54782/ProjectName/foo", and "localhost:54782/ProjectName/web/foo", and many other variations of this pattern.  Please help me and tell me what I need to do to view my foo.html and bar.html.

Comment: did you try localhost:54782/ProjectName/foo.html?

Answer (score 2):

You indicate that you tried localhost:54782/ProjectName/foo. Did you try it with the extension .html? if you did try it with localhost:54782/ProjectName/foo.html. It works by without the extension for index.html because there is a mapping defined in the web.xml file in the  tag.